# $\int_{[0,1)} \left|x^n - g(x)\right|^2 \to 0$ implies $g = 0$ if $g$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis

> I'm trying to prove that the following integral does not converge to $0$, unless $g = 0$, assuming $g$ continuous and without using Monotone/Dominated Convergence Theorem.
>
> $$\int_{[0,1)} \left|x^n - g(x)\right|^2 \, dx.$$

Let's fix $x_0 \in [0,1)$ and suppose $g(x_0) > 0$ (in the same way we
 could set $g(x_0) < 0$).
 By continuity of $g$: $$\exists U \ \text{open}, \ x_0 \in U \ : \
 \forall x\in U \quad  g(x) > \frac{g(x_0)}{2}$$

We have: $$\int_U \left|x^n - g(x)\right|^2 \, dx  >\int_U \left|x^n -
 \frac{g(x_0)}{2}\right|^2 \, dx > m(U) \inf_{x\in U}\left|x^n -
 \frac{g(x_0)}{2}\right|^2$$

Letting $n\to \infty$: $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\int_U |x^n - g(x)|^2 \ dx > m(U)\lim_{n \to \infty } \inf_{x\in U}\left|x^n -
 \frac{g(x_0)}{2}\right|^2 = m(U)\frac{g(x_0)^2}{4} > 0$$

Since 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,1)} \left|x^n - g(x)\right|^2 \, dx > \lim_{n
 \to \infty} \int_U \left|x^n - g(x)\right|^2 \, dx > 0,$$

the integral
$$\int_{[0,1)} \left|x^n - g(x)\right|^2 \, dx$$ does not converge to $0$ if $g \not = 0$ in at least one point of $[0,1)$.

---

I'm not so sure of these steps. In particular I'm worried about the exchange of limit and infimum in the second/third step.

Comment: Don't we need a compact $K \subset U$ to secure that the minimum exists?

Comment: @TienTruong Yes you are right. I made a mistake.

Comment: I've just read through your work properly. I think the 2:nd step is ok since $x \in [0, 1)$, $\lim_{n} x^n = 0$ and everything else is independent of $n$.

Comment: @TienTruong Thanks for you attention. I think is correct too, but I'm a bit timid about these things... I'm waiting for others opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your $U$ because there's nothing that excludes the possibility $U=[0,1).$ In that case the minimum over $U$ could be $0.$ We can fix that. Choose a positive $\delta < 1-x_0$ such that $g> g(x_0)/2$ in $[x_0,x_0+\delta].$ Then

$$\int_{[0,1)}|x^n-g(x)|^2\, dx \ge \int_{[x_0,x_0+\delta]|}|x^n-g(x)|^2\, dx.$$

On the last interval, $x^n-g(x) \to -g(x)$ uniformly, hence $|x^n-g(x)|^2 \to |g(x)|^2$ uniformly. So no fuss, no measure theory, the last integral converges to

$$\int_{[x_0,x_0+\delta]}|g(x)|^2\, dx > \delta\cdot (g(x_0)/2)^2>0.$$

This shows $\limsup \int_{[0,1)}|x^n-g(x)|^2 > 0,$ and we're done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Really useful. So you are using the interplay between Riemann Integral and uniform convergence right? Apart from the problem of U, is my inequality right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have by Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\int_0^1|x^n-g(x)|dx\leq \sqrt{\int_0^1|x^n-g(x)|^2 dx}$$

Now

$$|g(x)|\leq x^n+|x^n-g(x)|$$